# Add local image to R markdown pdf

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to add a local image to a R Markdown pdf output, in the chunk

add a picture

```
![image1](/C:/Users/User/Pictures/Capture.PNG)
```

it is displayed fine, so I would of thought it would come through to the knit file? But I get the error below
 
[pandoc warning] Could not find image `/C:/Users/User/Pictures/Capture.PNG', skipping...

Where am I going wrong? Do I have to get it to point in a different way if it's not in my working directory?

Comment: Try delete the slash before C:

Comment: `?knitr::include_graphics`

Comment: Deleting the slash didn't work  @jaySf

Comment: Put your image into same folder as your *.Rmd, then `![image1](Capture.PNG)`

Answer (score 1):

````
```{r}
file_AB <- "path/to/AB.png"
knitr::include_graphics(file_AB)
```
````

Comment: Editors, please stop deleting the \```{r} in my answer. This is important for context particularly because the code from the OP's initial proposal should not appear within a markdown chunk. The \```{r} in my response clarifies the location of the code and should remain.

Comment: appreciate the frustration, but it probably wouldn't have happened if you'd have written some explanation in your answer as well as code :)

Comment: Thanks @user438383, I'm not frustrated. Just clarifying now to avoid further back and forth.